# How to run Tensorflow on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed the GPU version of tensorflow on an Ubuntu 14.04.

I am on a GPU server where tensorflow can access the available GPUs.

I want to run tensorflow on the CPUs.

Normally I can use `env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` to run on GPU no. 0.

How can I pick between the CPUs instead?

I am not intersted in rewritting my code with `with tf.device("/cpu:0"):`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can apply `device_count` parameter per `tf.Session`:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(
        device_count = {'GPU': 0}
    )
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

See also protobuf config file:

[`tensorflow/core/framework/config.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L270)

Comment: Someone said running neural nets on CPUs after the training phase is as efficient as running them on GPUs -- i.e., only the training phrase really needs the GPU. Do you know if this is true? Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work for me (tf1.1). The solution of fabrizioM does.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable instead of changing the config in the code?

Comment: @Nandeesh I guess it depends on your needs. So far there are at least 53 people who feel more into environment variables and 35 who prefer to set number of devices in code. The advantage of first is simplicity and of another is more explicit control over (multiple) sessions from within the python program itself (that zero is not necessary to be hardcoded, it can be a variable).

Comment: @Crashalot it depends on the nature of the network. For example, RNNs can be faster on CPUs for small batch sizes due to its sequential nature. CNNs will still benefit from a GPU in inference mode, but since you only need to run them once per example, a CPU _may_ be fast enough for many practical purposes.

Comment: I prefer this one as sometimes you maybe want to run two networks simultaneously, a small network on CPU, while the bigger one is on GPU.

Comment: How does this configuration interact with `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Comment: Do you know how to adapt this to tensorflow 2.0, as there is no more session or configproto?

Comment: This indeed doesn't work anymore: check out my lower answer for something that works from 2.3.1 up.

Answer (score 215):

You can also set the environment variable to

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
```

without having to modify the source code.

Comment: Someone said running neural nets on CPUs after the training phase is as performant as running them on GPUs -- i.e., only the training phrase really needs the GPU. Do you know if this is true? Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot: This is not true. Look for various benchmarks for interference, CPUs are an order of magnitude slower there too.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. suggestions on which benchmarks to consider? probably also varies on workload and nature of the neural nets, right? apparently the google translate app runs some neural nets directly on smartphones, presumably on the cpu and not gpu?

Comment: @fabrizioM, a toy example will be more useful.

Comment: @Thomas, what I have observed is after the training is done and the model is frozen, doing predictions using the frozen model on CPU (around 3 ms) is slightly faster than on GPU (around 7 ms).

Comment: How do you hide it from tensorflow without hiding it from cuda? ie, I want something besides tensorflow in the same script to have access to the gpu

Comment: This did not work for me. :/ set the environment variable but tensorflow still uses the GPU, I'm using conda virtual env, does this make a diference?

Comment: However, if say we have no GPU devices, then does this solution still works? Or we have to use `{device_count = {'GPU':0}}`

Comment: Keep finding GPU. This may have worked on earlier versions of TF but not anymore.

Comment: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./learn_tf.py` works well on a Fedora 31, TensorFlow 2.1.0, and CUDA 10.2 system. CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES can also be a comma separated list of device ids. Effects entire program and so does not help if you want to have CUDA code and CPU-only TensorFlow in one program.

Comment: @Crashalot: for some datasets run with shallow models, the CPU is much faster even in the training phase because we can avoid the transfer time from memory to GPU on each batch.  Some data feeding/preloading techniques can reduce this gap, but it sometimes still persists.  95% of the time the GPU is faster, but sometimes it's worth checking performance on the CPU.

Comment: @mboss thanks for the answer! is it possible to describe the cases where the CPU is faster or comparable in speed?

Answer (score 166):

If the above answers don't work, try:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Comment: Just for the record, the first option doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Works also for tf 2.X when using `tf.keras.Sequential` models.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without tensorflow invoking the error message "CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected" ?

Answer (score 62):

The environment variable solution doesn't work for me running tensorflow **2.3.1**. I assume by the comments in the github thread that the below solution works for versions >=2.1.0.

From [tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31135):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Hide GPU from visible devices
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
```

Make sure to do this right after the import with fresh tensorflow instance (if you're running jupyter notebook, restart the kernel).

And to check that you're indeed running on the CPU:

```
# To find out which devices your operations and tensors are assigned to
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors and perform an operation
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

Expected output:

```
2.3.1
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Working with tensorflow and pytorch in one script, this approach help me to disable cuda on tensorflow but still make the pytorch use cuda. I believe this answer deserved more votes.

Comment: A potential advantage of this solution is that it doesn't rely on a variable that explicitly mentions CUDA and which might as such be reserved to specific devices. For example, it works on my Apple Silicon Mac.

Comment: Best solution, thx (because I'm on a Silicon too :D)

Comment: works for me like a charm. In Jupyter notebook, just follow these steps (based on above comment)
- Restart the Kernel --> put this line just beneath the tensorflow:  import tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')   --> run your script

Comment: this finally worked for me on tensorflow 2.7.0, thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows with TF 2.7. After running, I did `tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")` and got the same list of GPUs as before.

Comment: I can confirm this has worked for me on Apple Silicon M2.

Answer (score 39):

For me, only setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to precisely `-1` works:

Works:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('GPU found')
else:
    print("No GPU found")

# No GPU found
```

Does **not** work:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''    

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('GPU found')
else:
    print("No GPU found")

# GPU found
```

Comment: hi, does not work for me...I'm using tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1

Comment: Also failed for me on Windows with TF 2.7.

Comment: "GPU found" even of tf2.0

Answer (score 15):

As recommended by the [Tensorflow GPU guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement).

```
# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
  # Any additional tf code placed in this block will be executed on the CPU
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, for tensorflow 2.4.0, none of the previous answer works unless you install `tensorflow-cpu`

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

Comment: This works for tensorflow 2.5. But, I think my GPU for tensorflow 2.5 is no longer usable in the current environment after running the command. **(I tried the recommended way above and it doesn't work)

Comment: How to use this tensorflow-cpu with tf.io.decode_image?

Comment: Thank you, this also worked for TF 2.7 on Windows (Python 3.8)

Comment: Still works and seems up-to-date to this day, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just using the code below.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Comment: Did not work for me in Windows using TF 2.7

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution on installation level would be to look for [the CPU only variant](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location)

In my case, this gives right now:

```
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Just select the correct version (in this case, `cp38` hints `python 3.8` - moreover, *Tensorflow 2.2.0* is used, the current version as of Jul 12 '20).

---

Bonus points for using a **venv** like explained eg in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750900/4575793).

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Fabrizio's answer worked for me:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

I had to make the change before importing tensorflow.
I am using tensorflow 2.4.0

**2.** Another (sub par) solution could be to rename the *cusolver64_10.dll* file that is required for gpu computing. Since tensorflow can't find the dll, it will automatically use the CPU.

It should be in a place like:
*C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin*

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`tf.config.set_visible_devices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices). One possible function that allows you to set if and which GPUs to use is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def set_gpu(gpu_ids_list):
    gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        try:
            gpus_used = [gpus[i] for i in gpu_ids_list]
            tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus_used, 'GPU')
            logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
        except RuntimeError as e:
            # Visible devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
            print(e)
```

Suppose you are on a system with 4 GPUs and you want to use only two GPUs, the one with `id = 0` and the one with `id = 2`, then the first command of your code, immediately after importing the libraries, would be:

```
set_gpu([0, 2])
```

**In your case, to use only the CPU, you can invoke the function with an empty list**:

```
set_gpu([])
```

For completeness, if you want to avoid that the runtime initialization will allocate all memory on the device, you can use [`tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth).
Finally, the function to manage which devices to use, occupying the GPUs memory dynamically, becomes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def set_gpu(gpu_ids_list):
    gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        try:
            gpus_used = [gpus[i] for i in gpu_ids_list]
            tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus_used, 'GPU')
            for gpu in gpus_used:
                tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
            logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
        except RuntimeError as e:
            # Visible devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# this works on tensorflow 2.8, windows 10, jupyterlab Version 3.3.2
# this is the very FIRST lines of code

import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')

# if tf.test.gpu_device_name(): # this lies and tells you about all devices
if tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU'):
    print('GPU found')
else:
    print("No GPU found")
```

I spent way too many hours trying to figure this out.
MOST attempts left the process running partially on CPU and still loading into GPU memory?? Strange ...

Running the above code FIRST, before anything else worked.

I was able to increase my hidden later from 6k to 12k.
It is running now, only using the CPU.
Each epoch is taking about 10x as long as on the GPU.
From about 3 minutes per epoch to a bit over 35 minutes per epoch.
This is an acceptable trade-off. Training Time vs Model Size.

Comment: @user2489629 you might want to try listing physical devices instead of logical.

Answer (score -1):

In some systems one have to specify:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""  # or even "-1"
```

BEFORE importing tensorflow.