# How to force tensorflow to forget about the GPU, after it has been found?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow-based code which I am running on various computers, some with CPUs and some with both CPUs & GPUs.

If a GPU is available on the machine, I would like to give the user the option of using the CPU instead.

The code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539790/6145945) works fine:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('GPU found')
else:
    print("No GPU found")

# No GPU found
```

However, I would like to check if a GPU is available **first**, and then disable it.

I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    import os
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('GPU found')

# GPU found
```

But it does not work. Once I use `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`, it always remembers that the system has a GPU.

I also tried `del tf`, `importlib.reload(tf)`, to no avail. 
 The only thing that does work is to quit the interpreter and run the first script above.

How can I make the code "forget" about the GPU once it has been found?

Comment: Please don't artificially "tag" your titles with languages and frameworks. That's what actual _tags_ are for.

Comment: OK. sorry. I only left `tensorflow` as the tag, is that ok?

Comment: If it fits naturally into the title it's fine. It's things like "(python) How do I do foo?" or "Why does this give an AttributeError [python][django]" that's a problem. (The _real_ Python tag is fine. It has already been edited back.)

Comment: tldr; instead of writing a title like "(language) question?" or "language: question?", write it like "question?" and add the language [such as python] as a tag.

Comment: All right thanks, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to let the TensorFlow forget. You have GPU that doesn't mean you have to use GPU.

You can use [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement) to specify the underlying device.

For example:

```
# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

So even though you have GPU, the program will still use CPU.

Comment: Is there a way to set the CPU as the “global” device for all tensorflow calls in the interpreter?

Comment: Hum, if you modify your script that should be easy to implement. Just pass a variable to switch.

Comment: My slight issue is that I have entire classes and methods inside them that are using tensorflow all over the place. I wanted the user to be able to set a Boolean when creating an instance of the class. Boolean that sets whether the GPU or the CPU will be used for all tensorflow methods