# Tensorflow - Use CPU version

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I installed the tensorflow package in my anaconda base environment. I noticed that from version 2.1, it contains both CPU and GPU packages.
Now, while importing, the syntax will stay the same,
`import tensorflow as tf`

But if I want to use only the CPU version (when the network is small and running on GPU might be slower) or the GPU version (for the rest), how do I specify that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems simpler to just select appropriate device when doing computation. It can be done like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu):

```py
# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

in order to get the correct `/CPU:0` string for your case, use `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')`. It will return a list with correct device names.

You could also do `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""` in ubuntu terminal, before running your code. It will prevent using any GPU resource. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660312/how-to-run-tensorflow-on-cpu).